# Validating fields before submit

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core

I have this function that validates some form fields:

```
$('#FornecedorNovo').submit(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var url = "/Fornecedor/VerificaInscricao";
var Insc = $("#InscricaoEstadual").val();
var Isento = $("#InscricaoIsento").prop('checked');
var form = this,
    $form = $(form); // Salvamos o formulário atual em uma variável

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: { insc: Insc, isento: Isento },
        datatype: "json",
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.resultado == true) {
                $("#messageI").html(data.mensagem);
                if (data.mensagem != 'O campo Inscrição é obrigatório.') {
                    $("#InscricaoEstadual").val('');
                    $("#InscricaoEstadual").focus();
                }
            } else {
                var url1 = "/Fornecedor/VerificaDocumento";
                var Documento = $("#Documento").val();

                $.ajax({
                    url: url1,
                    data: { documento: Documento },
                    datatype: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.resultado == true) {
                            $("#message").html(data.mensagem);
                            $("#Documento").val('');
                            $("#Documento").focus();
                        }
                        else {
                            $form.off('submit').submit();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    })
});
```

But it happens that I have the validation already for dataannotations, and that's what I'm doing, if it falls into `$ form.off ('submit'). Submit ();`, it sends the form, without validating the fields, causing errors as they are required fields. Is there a way this does not occur? I use ASP.NET CORE.

Comment: `$form.off('submit')` is removing all submit event handlers on the form that jQuery has attached.  Given that is then does a submit(), that submit will not go through your validation.  I'm not sure what you are intending to do there....?

Comment: I need to validate the normal fields that have required, and those, however if the fields that have required are not filled, but the ones of this function is correct, it sends the form.

Comment: So what case does `data.resultado != true` represent?

Comment: It means that these fields are incorrect, needs to be changed. And if they are correct and the ones being validated by the no `dataannotations`, it sends anyway, returning error.

Comment: Ok, so is the goal to make the process repeat so they have to do the first ajax again?

Comment: The goal is to validate both ways, if any of them are incorrect, do not submit the form.

Comment: Is there a reason your not checking them before making the Ajax call?

Comment: So if you do not want to submit again, take off the `submit()`.  If you want them to start over the process you can remove the `off('submit')` and leave the submit

Comment: I'm getting this function because I can not do a validation with if in `dataannotations`. So besides the required, it needs to check this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not understanding why your using Ajax to make sure items aren't null?

you can check for them with

```
var error = false;
if(!$('#InscricaoIsento').is(':checked')){
    error = true;
    NotCheckedResponse();
}
if($("#InscricaoEstadual").val() == "" || $("#InscricaoEstadual").val() == null){
    error = true;
    NotFilledResponse();
}
if(!error){
    SubmitForm();
}
```

Unless I misunderstood something surely doing the checks like this would make it a lot simpler for you.